# What does vec( i:1:len) mean?

Tags: matlab, loops

Basically, I need to understand what this piece of code does ("blocks" is a vector):

```
len = length(blocks);
currsum = sum(abs(blocks(i:1:len)));
```

I know what the sum and abs does, it's just the last part, I know it's something to do with the loop, however, does it take a specific part of the vector and get the sum, or, does it sum the entire vector up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this into parts:

---

```
 i:len
```

Create a vector `[i, i+1, i+2,.... len]`. Recall that in Matlab the operator `vec(indexes)` selects the elements of the vector that are found in indexes.

```
 blocks(i:len)
```

Take the last k elements from the i'th up to the last.

```
 abs(  blocks(i:len) )
```

Absolute value of the last k elements.

```
 sum(abs(blocks(i:1:len)));
```

Sum of the absolute value of the last k elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So does this code therefore create a vector? "i:len" I'm trying to convert this code in C++ and although this makes sense, it doesn't in a way aha!